# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<dynamic>'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter i was making a catalog app and i m getting this error i tried every thing but i dont know how to fix it can any one guide me pls

The error occurs at this line:

```dart
_cart.items[index].name.text.make()
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxhcC.jpg).

i am using this so i can show items in the cart list but its giving me error (i am watching tutorial and its working fine for him but not for me)

i tried using curly  bracket etc even chat gbt but i m not getting this problem so if any one can guide me (plus its my first time asking a question excuse me for the mistakes) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

You're getting that error because the [[] operator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/operator_get.html) is defined for the [Iterable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) class.

### Solution:

You get an item at a particular index from an `Iterable` by using the [elementAt](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) method.

Update the line:

```dart
_cart.items[index].name.text.make()
```

to:

```dart
_cart.items.elementAt(index).name.text.make()
```

*Note:*

You can still use the `[]` operator but you will need to convert the `Iterable` to a [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) as `[]` operator is defined to get an item in a given index in a `List`.

The usage is shown below:

```dart
_cart.items.toList()[index].name.text.make()
```